# Função exec() - PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou tentando executar esse código simples e não estou conseguindo.
Não é por um erro, mas porque ele fica processando e não executa a função.
Sabem se pode ser uma questão de ambiente? 
Estou usando o **win7(64x)** e a versão mais atual do **wampserver**.

```php
<?php
exec('start /B calc.exe');      
?>
```

Antecipadamente, agradecida pela ajuda. rs

Comment: O que `calc.exe` faz?

Comment: executei aqui, no **Windows 10** utilizando **XAMPP** e funcionou tranquilo, minha versão do PHP é a *7.1.29*

Comment: Tenta dar um echo na exec(). e onde essa função está sendo carregada ? https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php Da uma fuçada aí também.

Comment: Quando você diz "função está sendo carregada", você está querendo dizer onde o arquivo php está salvo? Se for isso, ele está no www do meu wamp.

Comment: O calc.exe chama a calculadora do windows.

Comment: E a calculadora não abre?

Comment: Não. Eu testei no computador de um colega e esse mesmo código e a calculadora abriu. Por isso estou achando q pode ser algum problema de ambiente, mas q eu não faco ideia de qual seja. rs

Comment: se o arquivo da função também está no mesmo diretório.

Comment: Por ser uma aplicação nativa do windows, o calc.exe está em uma pasta do windows, já o meu script php está no servidor do wamp.

Comment: Não é necessário mudar o título para RESOLVIDO. Apenas marque a resposta apropriada como correta.